# How to make EditText auto resize when keyboard opens in different devices for Android

Tags: android

When I open my `EditText` on my app I see that my `EditText` opens to fullscreen. When I focus on `EditText` I need to resize this field for my keyboard automatically

[example of situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aM9jp.jpg)

My code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<EditText
android:id="@+id/etFName"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:gravity="top"
android:singleLine="false"
android:inputType="textMultiLine"
android:isScrollContainer="false" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnCancelPost"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="Cancel" />
```

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this code to your activity in AndroidManifest file

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

Comment: Thanks. That was my solution. My code for EditText: '    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etFName"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:singleLine="false"
    android:isScrollContainer="true"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"/>'